# Finding Corresponding Letter Counting from Opposite End of Alphabet and Removing From String Recursively JAVA

Tags: java, regex, recursion

Method should take in a word, recursively go thru the string and find letters that are the same distance from either end of the alphabet and remove them. If it removes a match, those letters cannot be used again. If every letter is removed, then it is a match.

`for (int i = 1; i < word.length()-1; i++)
            {
                if (word.charAt(0) + word.charAt(i) == 155)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);
                    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
                    sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                    String strNew = sb.toString();
                    System.out.println(strNew);
                    return isAlphaOpp(strNew);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }`

Comment: What kind of a problem are you facing ?

Comment: The issue that I'm facing is that it either isn't looping thru the string correctly, or sb is not removing the correct characters. So for example, words such as "by" "lazboy" and "wizard" should all come back as true, but instead they come back as false.

Comment: Got it, it seems your loop is wrong, let me take closer look

Comment: Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What, if anything, does your function print for the examples you cite above?  For example, if I follow your code, it should print "azby", "by", and "" for "lazyboy".

Comment: The example `lazboy` should return false correct? Also I didn't get why comparing with `155`.

Comment: I only have that println in there for testing purposes. The method prints out "AZBO" "ZO" "false" for "lazboy." There must be something wrong with the loop. The math should check out if I'm not mistaken. When it removes A it should remove Z but it instead removed B... Hmm.

Comment: lazboy, wizard, and by should return correct. Ex, b and y are equidistant from each end of the alphabet. I'm comparing it with 155 because if the two letters added together are == to 155, then they should be a match. Am I incorrect in my math?

Comment: That is because of you already deleted one character and deleting the second one, you should do `-1`

Comment: The ascii value for `b` is `98` and `y` is `121` so it should be `219` instead of 155.

Comment: Changed 155 to 219. I now receive: false false false for my output.
However, the reason that it is incorrect for you is because I'm passing thru toUpperCase() to make each letter uppercase, meaning it should be 155 as all letters are uppercase. I've now changed it to toLowerCase() to fit your code.

I will be eating dinner for around a half hour and I will return. I appreciate your ongoing help.

Comment: 155 is ONLY if all chars are uppercase. Otherwise, it is should be 219. First, convert it all to one case and then choose your value. BTW, why do you need this to be recursive? Unless you really want a recursive solution, you can do this by just looping. Just do a simple loop and any time, your chars don't add up to the value, return false. Otherwise, just continue in the loop.

Comment: You need to change your loop to for `(int i = 1; i <= word.length()-1; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your method a bit, have a look at it. You need compare with 155 if your string is all capitals, if all lower case letters you need compare with 219. As @Raghu suggested, this doesnt required recursion (that is making things complicated), but I am assuming you want to try this with recursion.

```
public static boolean isAlphaOpp (String word)
    {
        //if word has odd number of characters, it cannot be an alpha opp
        if (word.length() % 2 != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //if string makes it to 0, then word must be an alpha opp
        if (word.length() == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        /*if (word.charAt(0) + word.charAt(word.length()-1) == 155)
            {
                System.out.println(word.substring(1, word.length()-1));
                return isAlphaOpp(word.substring(1, word.length()-1));
            }
        */
        //Should go thru each letter and compare the values with char(0). If char(0) +     //char(i) == 155 (a match) then it should remove them and call the method again.
        int length = word.length()-1;
        int start = 0;
        String newStr = null;
        while(start < length) {

            if(word.charAt(start) + word.charAt(length) == 219) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);
                sb.deleteCharAt(length);
                sb.deleteCharAt(start);
                newStr = sb.toString();
                System.out.println(newStr);
                start++;
                length--;
                break;
            } else {
                start++;
            }
        }
        if(newStr != null) {
            return isAlphaOpp(newStr);
        }
        return false;
    }
```